# Preventing a PDF form from submitting if a certain criteria is not correct

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF form that has required checkboxes. I have these checkbox set to required, but the form still submits even if they are not set. It seems that others have had this problem. What I need to do is check if the the value of the checkbox is set to off. That I can do. What I am having a problem is how to prevent the form from submitting. I have tried return false but the syntax checkers say return is not a function.

```
if(this.getField('spelling').value = 'Off') {

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is use the submitForm() function.

```
if(this.getField('spelling').value != 'Off') {

    var aSubmitFields = new Array( "name", "id", "score" );
    this.submitForm({
        cURL: "http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/myscript.cgi#FDF",
        aFields: aSubmitFields,
        cSubmitAs: "FDF" // the default, not needed here
    });
}
```